# WordPress plugin localization, load_plugin_textdomain doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

Ok i built plugin for contact form, I wanna add translation for it. In my main plugin files i add this code

```
function ap_action_init() {
    // Localization
    load_plugin_textdomain('prijava_forma', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/languages";
}

// Add actions
add_action('init', 'ap_action_init');
```

in my file where contact form is written i have this

```
_e( 'Prva','prijava_forma' );
```

In my language folder I added the .mo and .po files created with Poedit.

Also I defined `WPLANG` in config.php and changed the language in the dashboard.

But i get no translation. Where could be problem, i am new to this?

Comment: Most probably the 3rd parameter (the path) is wrong

Comment: i got when echo, plugin_name/languages ? is that correct?

Comment: Check what the function returns instead: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain#Return_Values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible causes:

- .mo file not readable or not found at all (.po file is not used by WordPress by the way)
- The string you are expecting is not translated yet
- Wrong .mo file name, valid names are ar.mo, fr_FR.mo..., invalid ones are br_BR.mo, arabic.po, AR.mo, ar_AR.mo... So make sure you get this one right.
- for plugins the name will be the concatenation for the text domain, a dash and the locale: `myplugin-ru_RU.mo`

Check what [load_plugin_textdomain()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain#Return_Values) returned, if the .mo file was loaded, it should return true, in which case the next step would be to check that you are not missing the textdomain parameter in your `__()`, `_e()` and similar functions.

[More on WordPress localization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80335/17187)

Comment: Seems that my load_plugin_textdomain() returns false, name of my files are ru_RU, and ru_RU.mo ?

Comment: That's a valid locale, what about the file permissions?

Comment: Ahhh... the file name shoud be `prijava_forma-ru_RU.mo`

Comment: thank you 100 times! Work tell me only is it a way to prevent swiching cms language? Only to change plugin language?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65195/discussion-between-nabil-kadimi-and-vladimir-stus).

Answer (score 0):

It may be also caused on hook   where the functions is attached and where are the po/mo files.

On the Init Hooks, `load_plugin_textdomain()` returned `true` but string were not translated.

I changed the action to `plugins_loaded` as my po/mo were in a folder inside a Custom plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your string stands for itself. Do not append anything to the string, do this after the `gettext` function instead.

Wrong:

```
return __('Please translate me'.'(666)','your-textdomain');
```

Right:

```
return __('Please translate me','your-textdomain').'(666)';
```